# update an arrayResult of doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

i this query i get all of phones with certain condition
and one thing that i want after that is to set isFirstInstalled of all phones in this query to 1
also i want data of this query for api result
what is the most optimize way for that
the simplest way is using the result of the query in foreach and set one by one to 1 ?!
i want the result of my query before updating

```
$isFirstNotInstalledCases = $em->getRepository(User::class)
        ->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select("u.phone as phone")
        ->addSelect("u.isFirstInstalled as isFirstInstalled")
        ->where("u.phone IN (:phone)")
        ->andWhere("u.isFirstInstalled = :isFirstInstalled")
        ->setParameters(['isFirstInstalled'=>0,'phone'=>$phones])
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid foreach if you have not to do logic, use update better. Something like this:

```
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $q = $qb->update('App\User', 'u')
        ->set('u.isFirstInstalled', 1))
        ->where("u.phone IN (:phone)")
        ->andWhere("u.isFirstInstalled = :isFirstInstalled")
        ->setParameters(['isFirstInstalled'=>0,'phone'=>$phones])
        ->getQuery();
    $p = $q->execute();
```

Comment: @AAythaNzt your query doesn't select anything i want the result of my query before updating . would you help me for this logic?